# Cannot create "info@" address on two domains in Office 365 Exchange Admin center

Tags: exchange

I have two domains registered in Office 365 for two divisions in the same company.  Let's say `orangeco.com` and `tomatoinc.net`.  I have created multiple licensed users on each domain without problem, of course.  I also had previously created some "shared" support addresses for Orange Co., including `info@orangeco.com`, `admin@orangeco.com` etc.

The problem I'm having is that now I'm trying to create similar addresses for Tomato Inc. but it's throwing an error.  For instance, if I try to create `info@tomatoinc.net` I get this error:

> The proxy address "SMTP:info@orangeco.com" is already being used by the proxy addresses or LegacyExchangeDN. Please choose another proxy address.

Is it possible to have the same address at both domains?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason creating `info@orangeco.com` also tries to automatically add an SMTP alias for `info@tomatoinc.net`.

On the Shared mailbox creation dialog you can click "More Options" and enter a unique alias, ie `info.tomato`.  This allows you to create the mailbox. You can then edit the entry and remove the SMTP alias for `info.tomato@orangeco.com`.